# Flutter Bloc Library

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

In an application I am trying to implement the cart functionality. ItemDetailsScreen has addItemBtn, which returns null after the item is added. This function works fine, but the problem is that when I go to cartScreen and clear the cart, and then go back to ItemDetailsScreen, addItemBtn still returns null. To return  the add state, I must use a hot reload. It looks like the state is not updating !? So how to solve this?

addItemBtn:

```
   BlocBuilder<CartFunctionsCubit, CartFunctionsState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return state.map(
          initial: (_) => Container(),
          cartLoaded: (state) => FlatButton(
            onPressed: state.userCart.items.contains(item)
                ? null
                : () {
                    context.read<CartFunctionsCubit>().addToCart(item);
                    context.read<CartFunctionsCubit>().startApp();
                  },
            child: state.userCart.items.contains(item)
                ? Text('Added')
                : Text('Add'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Cubit:

```
 Future<void> startApp() async {
    final userCart = await cartFacade.getUserCart();

    emit(CartFunctionsState.cartLoaded(userCart: userCart));
  }

  Future<void> addToCart(Item item) async {
    cartFacade.addToCart(item);
  }
```

Navigate to cart screen I am using

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/cart');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can await push function and then call the  `context.read<CartFunctionsCubit>().startApp();`

```
await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/cart');
 context.read<CartFunctionsCubit>().startApp();
```

It will refresh the data when you came back from cart page

And if you want change the data when you change something in cart page. give boolean in `Navigator.pop()`

**In Cart Page**

```
 bool needToRefresh = false/// when there is a change set needToRefresh = true
    Navigator.pop(context,needToRefresh );/// and pass the value here
```

**In Item Details Screen**

```
bool needToRefresh = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/cart');
if(needToRefresh !=null && needToRefresh)
   context.read<CartFunctionsCubit>().startApp();
```

It will refresh the data only when **needToRefresh** is **true**;